# html5 or css 'smart text flow' to evenly distribute a sentence or paragraph over equally wide lines?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment, text-align, textflow

Suppose I have a dynamic HTML element (a `span` or `div` or whatever) with a sentence or paragraph of text inside, like this:

[image: two lines]

Now if I make the sentence slightly longer, it might need an extra line, like this:

[image: three lines wrong]

Note how the last word is on a separate line. So the first two lines are full occupied. In the sense that they take up the entire available with in this element. And the third line contains only one word and remains mostly empty.

I find this rather disturbing, and I wonder if there is a trick to distribute the free space more evenly amongst all lines. I mean like this: (note that this is the exact same sentence)

[image: three lines right]

It should re-flow automatically depending on font and browser view size, and width of the element, which may depend on screen resolution.

Is there some clever HTML5 or CSS3 way to achieve this?

Upon searching and looking in topics similar to this question, I did find the `text-align: justify` property which I am familiar with but isn't really what I'm looking for. 
`text-align: justify` tends to extend all lines to the full with of the containing element by increasing the whitespace between words.

Instead, what I'm really looking for is something that redistributes the words so that all lines are narrower i.e. not take up all horizontal element space. In a way that results in all lines being equally wide (or approximating this as close as possible).

So I mean NOT like this: (which is what `text-align:justify` does)

[image: text-align justify]

Compare this to the previous example above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you asked for a CSS solution but I don't think there is one yet. Below is my JS solution for the meantime.

```js
function createBetterLineBreaks(el) {
  var originalWidth = el.offsetWidth;
  var originalHeight = el.offsetHeight;
  for (let i = originalWidth - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    el.style.width = `${i}px`;
    if (el.offsetHeight > originalHeight) {
      el.style.width = `${i + 1}px`;
      break;
    }
  }
}
// hover effects
document.querySelector('.box').addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  createBetterLineBreaks(document.querySelector('.box .text'));
});
document.querySelector('.box').addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  document.querySelector('.box .text').style.width = 'unset';
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><span class="text">hover this box to distribute the text more evenly</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a very nice approach!

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the CSS [Text Module 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-4/) property [`text-wrap: balance`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-4/#text-wrap). It has been proposed but unfortunately not yet implemented, so in the meantime, use this jQuery polyfill [balance-text](https://github.com/adobe/balance-text).

```js
balanceText();
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.balance-text {
  text-wrap: balance;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/balance-text@3.3.0/balancetext.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"><span class="text balance-text">The words in this sentence cause it to require three lines.</span></div>
```